# Adding items in RecyclerView from the data that comes from an intent not behaving properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Adding items in RecyclerView from the data that comes from an intent that brings the data from another activity not behaving as expected.

This is the Main Activity of the app:

```
package com.example.android.contacts;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView contactListView;
    private ViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent intent2 = getIntent();
        String nameTxt = intent2.getStringExtra("ContactName");
        String phoneTxt = intent2.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
        String emailTxt = intent2.getStringExtra("Email");
        String addressTxt = intent2.getStringExtra("Address");

        contactListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        getData(nameTxt,phoneTxt,emailTxt,addressTxt);

        adapter = new ViewAdapter(getApplication(), getData(nameTxt,phoneTxt,emailTxt,addressTxt));
        contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    public  List<Contact> getData(String name, String phone, String email, String address){
        List<Contact> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new Contact(name,phone,email,address));

        return data;
    }

    public void addNewContact (View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent (Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

This is the Adapter :

```
package com.example.android.contacts;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    List<Contact> data = Collections.emptyList();


    public ViewAdapter (Context context, List<Contact> data){
        inflator=LayoutInflater.from(context);

        this.data=data;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Contact current = data.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(current.getName());
        holder.phone.setText(current.getPhone());
        holder.email.setText(current.getEmail());
        holder.address.setText(current.getAddress());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        TextView phone;
        TextView email;
        TextView address;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            phone=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            email=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
            address=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

The activity gets the data from another activity and the data comes into the main activity utilizing an intent, and the part of data receiving to the main activity is tested and works as expected.

This is the activity that feeds the data to the main Activity:

```
package com.example.android.contacts;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nameTxt, phoneTxt, emailTxt, addressTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        phoneTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
        emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        addressTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);

    }
    public void addContact (View view){

        if (nameTxt.getText().length()==0){

            nameTxt.setError("Please enter the Name");

        }

        else if (phoneTxt.getText().length()==0){

            phoneTxt.setError("Please enter the Phone Number");

        }

        else if (emailTxt.getText().length()==0){

            emailTxt.setError("Please enter the Email");

        }

        else if (addressTxt.getText().length()==0){

            addressTxt.setError("Please enter the Address");

        }

        else{

            Intent intent = new Intent (this, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ContactName",nameTxt.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("PhoneNumber",phoneTxt.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Email",emailTxt.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Address",addressTxt.getText().toString());

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you not adding anything to your list....it´s empty...look into your getData() method...

Comment: Uncomment "data.add(...)" and try to add something in it.

Comment: Code you shared have commented line //data.add(new Contact(name,phone,email,address));

Comment: remove `//` at `data.add` from the `getData()` method.....I think you have to learn more basics before using a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It´s a simple thing but I want to show you, what the problem is. I guess you are not understanding what we want to explain in the comments. No problem, everybody has started off small (like we say in Germany) :). So here is your problem:

```
public  List<Contact> getData(String name, String phone, String email, String address){
        List<Contact> data = new ArrayList<>();
        //data.add(new Contact(name,phone,email,address));

        return data;
    }
```

The two slashes `//` means that you have commented the code out. So it is not active anymore. To add these values to your list, you have to remove that slashes. It must look like this:

```
public  List<Contact> getData(String name, String phone, String email, String address){
        List<Contact> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new Contact(name,phone,email,address));

        return data;
    }
```

Do you see the difference? Also here in that post, in your example, it´s grayed out...

Comment: and if this is still not the problem, then show us where you start your activity. If you have an intent that passes values, there must be another activity which starts your mainActivity.

Comment: AND don´t add the comment slashes again. No matter which problem it is, it is wrong. It could not work with that...

Comment: i added the activity that i get the data from

Comment: Sorry now I am more confused.. first of all, please don´t post additional information as an answer. put it into your question, please. And second, where are you calling `addContact()` in your first activity? There is no call....

Comment: And please be more specific...what exactly is the problem? Is there any error? Did your app crash? Do you just ee nothing?

Comment: sorry for my mistake because i am a beginner here.

Comment: i don't rally know where to call the  addContact().

Comment: you need a button that calls this method. You can call the method after user has finished his input. And then let the user push a button and call addContact()....

Comment: is this your problem, you have no idea how to start the other activity?

Comment: addContact() is a onClick method

Comment: this is not the main activity

Comment: i start with the recycledView acivity and go to the other activity with an other button

Comment: a onClick method from your layout.xml I guess...? And, for clearence: You second activity starts?

Comment: the activities are starting correctly but i can not add the items in the RecycledView

Comment: but if you start with the recyclerView, you have no data.....there could nothing be transferred.....you must start with the MainActivity to get data and pass this data..

Comment: there is an intent addNewContact that starts the second activity

Comment: after i start without data i have the button to go and put the data. and than i have another button that brings the data and starts the activity

Comment: maybe it´s a stack problem. First, your recyclerView is started,then you press a button that leads you to the input activity. The user makes the input and presses a button that leads him again to the recyclerView activity. Is that the correct way your app works? If yes, maybe it´s a  stack problem. Just try some: in that part where you starting the input activity from the recyclerView activity, call finish() as last. It´s possible that you get no data via intent because your recyclerView activity is still alive and you just go back to it.